# Export To Excel Only Got The First Purchase Order Parts List

Tags: infor-eam

I am new to Infor EAM and I am having problem with the export to excel which only created for the first data, like for example purchase order. When displaying a purchase order, in parts tab, and I download the excel for the parts list. Then, I select another purchase order, when I download the parts list it only shows the previous parts list from the first purchase order. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not exist in IE explorer. This is a known issue by Infor, and they fixed this in 11.4 version of Infor EAM

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure, but it looks like caching problem in browser. I’ve had issue like you described with Google Chrome. Try to use another browser or change cache settings. I solved this problem by using IE11.